# Using pipe character as a field separator

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm trying different commands to process csv file where the separator is the pipe `|` character.

While those commands do work when the comma is a separator, it throws an error when I replace it with the pipe:

```
awk -F[|] "NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next}$2 in a{ print a[$2] [|] $4 [|] $5 }" OFS=[|] file1.csv file2.csv

awk "{print NR "|" $0}" file1.csv
```

I tried, `"|"`, `[|]`, `/|` to no avail.

I'm using Gawk on windows. What I'm I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `\|` as in, e.g., `awk -F\| '{ print NF }' bar.txt` ?

Comment: What does your data look like? What is the error?

Comment: it is a problem in your `print`. Just use commas to separate fields, as I indicate in my answer.

Comment: Your attempt to use `"|"` doesn't work because all you did was close the quotes, then put an unescaped pipe, then reopen them. You need to use different quotes: `awk '{ print NR "|" $0}'` and `/|` doesn't work because that's not even an escape character!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone finding this years later: ALWAYS QUOTE SHELL METACHARACTERS!

I think gawk (GNU awk) treats `|` specially, so it should be quoted (for `awk`). OP had this right with `[|]`. However `[|]` is also a shell pattern. Which in `bash` at least, will only expand *if* it matches a file in the current working directory:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ echo -F[|]    # Same command
-F[|]
$ touch -- '-F|'
$ echo -F[|]    # Different output
-F|
$ echo '-F[|]'  # Good quoting
-F[|]           # Consistent output
```

So it should be:

```
awk '-F[|]'
# or
awk -F '[|]'
```

`awk -F "[|]"` would also work, but IMO, only use soft quotes (`"`) when you have something to actually expand (or the string itself contains hard quotes (`'`), which can't be nested in any way).

Note that the same thing happens if these characters are inside unquoted variables.

If **text** or a **variable** contains, or may contain: `[]?*`, quote it, or `set -f` to turn off pathname expansion (a single, unmatched square bracket is technically OK, I think).

If a **variable** contains, or may contain an IFS character (space, tab, new line, by default), quote it (unless you *want* it to be split). Or `export IFS=` first (bearing the consequences), if quoting is impossible (eg. a crazy `eval`).

Note: raw text is always split by white space, regardless of IFS.

Answer (score 6):

You tried `"|"`, `[|]` and `/|`. `/|` does not work because the escape character is `\`, whereas `[]` is used to define a range of fields, for example `[,-]` if you want `FS` to be either `,` or `-`.

To make it work `"|"` is fine, are you sure you used it this way? Alternativelly, escape it --> `\|`:

```
$ echo "he|llo|how are|you" | awk -F"|" '{print $1}'
he
$ echo "he|llo|how are|you" | awk -F\| '{print $1}'
he
$ echo "he|llo|how are|you" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {print $1}'
he
```

But then note that when you say:

```
print a[$2] [|] $4 [|] $5
```

so you are not using any delimiter at all. As you already defined `OFS`, do:

```
print a[$2], $4, $5
```

Example:

```
$ cat a
he|llo|how are|you
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} {print $1, $3}' a
he|how are
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the `|`

```
echo "more|data"  | awk -F\| '{print $1}'
more
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the `|` as `\|`

```
$ cat test
hello|world
$ awk -F\| '{print $1, $2}' test
hello world
```