# Using multiple delimiters when one of them is a pipe character

Tags: awk, csv

I have a text file where fields are separated by a pipe character.  Since it is a human readable text, there are spaces used for column alignment.

Here is a sample input:

```
+------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
|  Column1  |   Column2    |   Column3     |    Column4     |   Last Column    |
+------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| some_text |  other_text  |  third_text   |   fourth_text  |  last_text       |
<more such lines>
+------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
```

How can I use awk to extract the third field in this case?  The
I tried:

```
awk -F '[ |]' '{print $3}' file
awk -F '[\|| ]' '{print $3}' file
awk -F '[\| ]' '{print $3}' file
```

The expected result is:

```
<blank>
Column3
<more column 3 values>
<blank>
third_text
```

I am trying to achieve this with a single awk command.  Isn't that possible?

The following post talks about using pipe as a delimiter in awk but it doesn't talk about the case of multiple delimiters where one of them is a pipe character:

- [Using pipe character as a field separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246584/using-pipe-character-as-a-field-separator)

Comment: Duplicate of [Using pipe character as a field separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246584/using-pipe-character-as-a-field-separator)

Comment: It's not a duplicate - that post doesn't deal with multiple delimiters.

Comment: "none of them work" is the worst possible problem description. Do you want the fields to include white space or not? Whats the expected output?

Comment: It's not clear that the code you provided is actually what was tried. Two of the lines seem to lack closing quotes. And you don't say what actual results are. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is this `mysql` output?

Comment: It's not MySQL output.  It's generated by a script.  Also, fixed typos in my question and added more info to indicate what output I am expecting.

Comment: Assuming that you're trying to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces, the simplest solution is `awk -F\| {sub(/^  */, "", $3);sub(/  *$/,"", $3); print $3}' file`  ... `gsub(/^  *|  *$/, "", $3)` might also work.. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Am I missing something ?

Example input :

```
+------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
|  Column1  |   Column2    |   Column3     |    Column4     |   Last Column    |
+------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| some_text |  other_text  |  third_text   |   fourth_text  |  last_text       |
| some_text2|  other_text2 |  third_text2  |   fourth_text2 |  last_text2      |
+------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
```

Command :

```
gawk -F '[| ]*' '{print $4}' <file>
```

Output :

```
<blank>
Column3
<blank>
third_text
third_text2
<blank>
```

Works for every column (you just need to use `i+1` instead of `i` because first column empty values or `+-----`).

Comment: That would work in every awk, not just the two you mention. `print` is a builtin, not a function, btw so you can just write `print $4`, no need for parens around the $4.

Answer (score 1):

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl) is better suited for this use case :

```
$ perl -F'\s*\|\s*' -lane 'print $F[3]' File
#      ____________
#           ^
#           |
#  FULL regex support with -F switch (delimiter, like awk, but more powerful)
```

Comment: awk also supports regexps as the delimiter. `gawk -F'\\s*\\|\\s*' '{print $3}' File` would do the same as your perl script. In other awks that don't support the `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]` you'd just use `awk -F'[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*' '{print $3}' File`.

Answer (score 0):

First preparse with `sed` - remove first, third and last line, replace all spaces+|+spaces with a single |, remove leading | - then just split with awk using `|` (could be really `cut -d'|' -f3`).

```
sed '1d;3d;$d;s/ *| */|/g;s/^|//;' |
awk -F'|' '{print $3}'
```